# People picker show user in groups

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My company have about 6000 people, all of them are in AD. We have a big SharePoint portal and some sub SharePoint portal for internal use only. All of them are MOSS 2010. Each sub-portal have their own user groups. My question is, How can I config People Picker dialog to display sub portal groups and will display all user in that group when user choose. I do that be cause every times user want to add a people, they have to find/search through a list of 6000 people. We need to display a local group so they can choose quicker.

For example: We have Group A (100people) Group B(100people)... We want to select 50 people from group A then search in people picker will be problematic

Please help

Comment: How is declared the PeoplePicker?

Comment: What do you means?

Comment: The PeoplePicker is a control, that can be declared in a custom page or webpart, automatically generated by SharePoint if you have a list with a user field, generated by you from a feature in Visual studio, etc.

Comment: Ah, we use people picker in a SharePoint form, (design by infopath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discover a way to do that using javascript. Modify `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Picker.aspx` ,add some combobox to select group.

List all group with following code:

```
var siteUrl = '/';
var groupsCallback = function(a){
    console.debug(a);
}
function retrieveAllUserGroups(callback) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    groupsCallback = callback || groupsCallback;
    this.collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    clientContext.load(collGroup);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onGroupsQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onGroupsQueryFailed));
}

function onGroupsQuerySucceeded() {
    var groupEnumerator = collGroup.getEnumerator();
    var SPG = [];
    while (groupEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oGroup = groupEnumerator.get_current();
        var gjson = {
            'id':           oGroup.get_id(),
            'title':        oGroup.get_title(),
            'description':  oGroup.get_description()
        }
        SPG.push(gjson);
    }
    if (groupsCallback){
        groupsCallback(SPG);
    }
}

function onGroupsQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

To list user from a group use this code:

```
function retrieveAllUsersInGroup(gid, callback) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    usersCallback = callback || usersCallback;
    var collGroup = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
    var oGroup = collGroup.getById(gid);
    this.collUser = oGroup.get_users();
    clientContext.load(collUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUsersQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUsersQueryFailed));
}
```

`gid` is the group id taken from above code. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about in Infopath, but the PeopleEditor control itself has a property '[SharePointGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor.sharepointgroup)', which would only let you select users from within that group.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but then we can only select from that group. Not the others when we want. All I want is that it can search by group or filter by groups somehow